# Is this Hebrew reading without vocalization dots correct for Leviticus 12:4?

Tags: hebrew, masoretic-text

I read from Isaac Oliver's quote in
[*Gentilizing Luke’s ‘Most’ Jewish ‘Moment’: Reassessing the Circumcision, Purification, and Redemption of Jesus*](https://www.academia.edu/3271010/Gentilizing_Luke_s_Most_Jewish_Moment_Reassessing_the_Circumcision_Purification_and_Redemption_of_Jesus) p.8 footnote:

> Without the vocalization, the Masoretic Text of Lev 12:4 proves more ambiguous: bothדמי טהרה  andימי טהרה  could be read without the *mappiq* on the final *he* to mean “blood of purification” and “days of purification,” respectively, rather than the blood and days of *her* purification. The Masoretes add a *mappiq* to the second nominal construction to clarify that the text is speaking of “days of her purification.”

I need to confirm this from Hebrew experts, and the possibility that if the Hebrew text was originally ambiguous in *not* specifying "her" to indicate the mother. And if we have this verse in the DSS? The [vocalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Niqqud) markings are said to be added in the second half of the first millennium AD.

Lev 12:4  וּשְׁלֹשִׁ֥ים יוֹם֙ וּשְׁלֹ֣שֶׁת יָמִ֔ים תֵּשֵׁ֖ב בִּדְמֵ֣י טָהֳרָ֑ה בְּכָל־ קֹ֣דֶשׁ לֹֽא־ תִגָּ֗ע וְאֶל־ הַמִּקְדָּשׁ֙ לֹ֣א תָבֹ֔א עַד־ מְלֹ֖את יְמֵ֥י טָהֳרָֽהּ׃

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, the text in this section is reliable.  There is no reference to any variant in the Versions.  If you're curious, here are the Versions:

### The Status of the text

**LXX**

- “καὶ τριάκοντα ἡμέρας καὶ τρεῖς καθίσεται ἐν αἵματι ἀκαθάρτῳ αὐτῆς· παντὸς ἀγγίου οὐχ ἅψεται, καὶ εἰς τὸ ἁγιαστήριον οὐκ εἰσελεύσεται, ἕως ἂν πληρωθῶσιν αἱ ἡμέραι καθάρσεως αὐτῆς.” (Leviticus 12:4 LXXS-T)
- And for 30 days and three she will sit down in her unclean blood. Every leather she will not touch. And into the holy place she will not go int, until the days of her cleansing are fulfilled."

**Vulgate**

- “ipsa vero triginta tribus diebus manebit in sanguine purificationis suae omne sanctum non tanget nec ingredietur sanctuarium donec impleantur dies purificationis eius” (Leviticus 12:4 VULG-T)
- "She herself, for 33 days will remain in the blood of her own purification. she will not touch any holy thing, nor will she go into the holy place until the days of his purification are completed."

**Syriac**

- ”ܘܬܠܬܝܢ ܘܬܠܬܐ ܝܘܡ̈ܝܢ ܬܬܒ ܥܠ ܕܡܐ ܕܟܝܐ. ܘܒܟܠ ܩܘܕܫܐ ܠܐ ܬܬܩ݁ܪܒ. ܘܠܡܩܕܫܐ ܠܐ ܬܥܘܠ. ܥܕܡܐ ܕܢܡ݂ܠܘܢ ܝܘܡ̈ܝ ܕܟܝܘܬܗ݁.“ (Leviticus 12:4 PESHOT-T)
- "And 30 and 3 days on the blood of purity. And in every holy [thing] she shall not approach. And she shall not enter the sanctuary until the days of her purification are filled up."

All of these versions show that the text is stable. And there is no variant reading in the apparatus (esp. the DSS).

### The meaning of the words

As Perry admirably points out the discussion is over one dot at the end of a word.  The first time we read the word, we read: "טָהֳרָ֑ה" (purification). The second time there's a mappiq at the end of the word (טָהֳרָֽהּ). If there's a mappiq, a dot in the "he" (ה) at the end of the word, then it changes from purification to *her* purification.

However, whether or not there is a mappiq in the text or not it changes very little.  Hebrew does not have a reflexive pronoun (sua, in latin; ⲁⲩⲧⲏ in Greek). So "her" could either mean "her" (another woman) or "herself" (the specific woman in context).

The pointing is not part of the original text.  We trust and rely on it. For the Masoretes did a faithful job of handing down the text to us and even helping us out with the vowel structure. But there might be places where we divide the text phrasing differently or wonder about the pointing. Here might be an example. But, even if the mappiq is added it does not change the ambiguity of the text itself ("her" can either mean the woman who is bleeding, or another woman). Context then is our best determiner of meaning.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is whether טֹהַר is a masculine noun with the feminine singular suffix, meaning "her," or is טָהֳרָה a feminine noun. If you remove the masorah, vocalization not in the original text, the ending of the feminine noun and the suffix meaning her and the masculine noun are indistinguishable.   Thus, the following two lexicons quote below take differing interpretations confirming Isaac's statements about the ambiguity.

> טָהֳרָה SamP.BenH. ṭarra: **fem. of טֹהַר**, Bauer-L. Heb. 601b; MHeb. טַהֲרָה, DSS טה(ו)רה; Pun. טהרת Jean-H. Dictionnaire 100: טָהֳרַת, טָהֳרָתוֹ: —1. (ceremonial) cleanness, טָהֳרַת קֹדֶשׁ 2C 30:19. —2. establishment of ceremonial cleanness Lv 13:7, 35 14:2, 23, 32 15:13 Nu 6:9 Ezk 44:26 Neh 12:45; —3. cleansing, purifying 1C 23:28; —Lv 12:4f דְּמֵי טָהֳרָה blood of purifying (? rd. דְּ׳ ־רָהּ). -
> Koehler, L., Baumgartner, W., Richardson, M. E. J., & Stamm, J. J. (1994–2000). In *The Hebrew and Aramaic lexicon of the Old Testament* (electronic ed., p. 370). E.J. Brill.

> †טֹ֫הַר S2892 TWOT792a GK3198 **n.[m.]** purity, purifying— 1. purity, כְּעֶצֶם הַשָּׁמַיִם לָטֹ֫הַר Ex 24:10 (JE), as the body of the heavens for purity. 2. sf. יְמֵי טָהֳרָהּ Lv 12:4, 6 the days of her purifying (menstruation).-
> Brown, F., Driver, S. R., & Briggs, C. A. (1977). In *Enhanced Brown-Driver-Briggs Hebrew and English Lexicon* (p. 372). Clarendon Press.

Comment: I dont understand anything from this. Explain to someone who doesnt know Hebrew and just simply verify the quote if the original text ambiguous?

Comment: @Michael Does that edit make it clear enough?

Comment: Not at all. I dont understand Hebrew. Is the quote correct that the original without vocalization is ambiguous without mentioning "her"? And is it a matter of interpretation? If taken without vocalization, can we translate it without "her"?

Comment: @Michael How about now?